# Имя пользователя null

Tags: android, firebase, auth, null

Здравствуйте.Использую Firebase aut в приложении и когда я хочу получить имя пользователя у меня отображаеться null

Вот код где указывается имя пользователя

```
    public void EditProfile(View v)
        {
            userName = username.getText().toString().trim();
            userProfileUris = u1s;
            UserProfileChangeRequest profileChangeRequest = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                    .setDisplayName(userName)
                    .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(userProfileUris))
                    .build();
            firebaseUser.updateProfile(profileChangeRequest).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Профиль создан" + " " + firebaseUser.getDisplayName() ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //Здесь также getDisplayName дает null
                    startActivity(new Intent(ProfileEditActv.this, ProfileActv.class));
                    ProfileEditActv.this.finish();
                }
            });
        }
```

Это код где я получаю имя пользователя

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_actv);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        USER = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        Toast.makeText(this,mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName() + " " + mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ProfileName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PName);
        ProfileEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PEmail);
        ProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        UpdateProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.UProfile);
        if(USER != null)
        {
            ProfileName.setText(USER.getDisplayName());
            ProfileEmail.setText(USER.getEmail());
            ProfileImage.setImageURI(USER.getPhotoUrl());
        }
    }
```